# How can I use specific keys of dictionary to plot a graph

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

Hi Is there some way to use specific keys of a dictionary using matplotlib to plot a graph?

So, my dictionary is the following:

```
dict= {"USA":234, "ARG":225,
    "SPN": 245, "CAN": 205
    "RO": 345, "MEX": 210}
```

What I want, is to plot the keys that I specify (with their values), not all of them.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please share an example of something you tried and that you expected to work, or your best attempt. What part of the problem are you having trouble with? Selecting elements from a dictionary? Looping over a number of elements? Putting a group of elements on a chart? Creating a specific type of chart?

Comment: Delete the keys you don't want.

Comment: My dictionary is actually way bigger, it has around 20000 keys, so I can't delete the keys I don't want as they are many keys

Comment: **Never** use built-in data types (`dict`), methods, etc., as a variable name, even in a dummy example.

Answer (score -1):

You can filter with a `dict comprehension`:

```
d = {"USA":234, "ARG":225,
    "SPN": 245, "CAN": 205,
    "RO": 345, "MEX": 210}
wanted_keys = ['USA', 'ARG']
d_plot = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in wanted_keys}
```

Do not use `dict` as a variable name for it is a designated word in python.

Answer (score -1):

Hi try to use the below code:

```
#import matplotlib and numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
dict= {"USA":234, "ARG":225,
    "SPN": 245, "CAN": 205,
    "RO": 345, "MEX": 210}
# use x as a key of the dict. and y as the value
x=np.array(list(dict.keys()))
y=np.array(list(dict.values()))
# plot x,y and choose the key and value number
plt.plot(x[[0,1,3]],y[[0,1,3]])
```